# What exactly makes a type system consistent?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, agda, lambda-calculus

I've taken András Kovács's [DBIndex.hs](https://github.com/AndrasKovacs/tcbe/blob/master/DBIndex.hs), a very simple implementation of a dependently typed core, and tried simplifying it even further, as much as I possibly could, without "breaking" the type system. After several simplifications, I was left with something much smaller:

```
{-# language LambdaCase, ViewPatterns #-}

data Term
  = V !Int
  | A Term Term
  | L Term Term
  | S
  | E
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data VTerm
  = VV !Int
  | VA VTerm VTerm
  | VL VTerm (VTerm -> VTerm)
  | VS
  | VE

type Ctx = ([VTerm], [VTerm], Int)

eval :: Bool -> Term -> Term
eval typ term = err (quote 0 (eval term typ ([], [], 0))) where

  eval :: Term -> Bool -> Ctx -> VTerm
  eval E _ _ = VE
  eval S _ _ = VS
  eval (V i) typ ctx@(vs, ts, _) = (if typ then ts else vs) !! i
  eval (L a b) typ ctx@(vs,ts,d) = VL a' b' where
    a' = eval a False ctx
    b' = \v -> eval b typ (v:vs, a':ts, d+1)
  eval (A f x) typ ctx = fx where
    f' = eval f typ ctx
    x' = eval x False ctx
    xt = eval x True ctx
    fx = case f' of
      (VL a b) -> if check a xt then b x' else VE -- type mismatch
      VS       -> VE -- non function application
      f        -> VA f x'

  check :: VTerm -> VTerm -> Bool
  check VS _ = True
  check a  b = quote 0 a == quote 0 b

  err :: Term -> Term
  err term = if ok term then term else E where
    ok (A a b) = ok a && ok b
    ok (L a b) = ok a && ok b
    ok E = False
    ok t = True

  quote :: Int -> VTerm -> Term
  quote d = \case
    VV i    -> V (d - i - 1)
    VA f x  -> A (quote d f) (quote d x)
    VL a b  -> L (quote d a) (quote (d + 1) (b (VV d)))
    VS      -> S
    VE      -> E

reduce :: Term -> Term
reduce = eval False

typeof :: Term -> Term
typeof = eval True
```

The problem is that I have no idea what makes a type system consistent, so I had no criteria (other than intuition) and probably broke it in several ways. It, more or less, does what I think a type system should do, though:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  --  id = ∀ (a:*) . (λ (x:a) . a)
  let id = L S (L (V 0) (V 0))

  --  nat = ∀ (a:*) . (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
  let nat = L S (L (L (V 0) (V 1)) (L (V 1) (V 2)))

  --  succ = λ (n:nat) . ∀ (a:*) . λ (s : a -> a) . λ (z:a) . s (n a s z)
  let succ = L nat (L S (L (L (V 0) (V 1)) (L (V 1) (A (V 1) (A (A (A (V 3) (V 2)) (V 1)) (V 0))))))

  --  zero = λ (a:*) . λ (s : a -> a) . λ (z : a) . z
  let zero = L S (L (L (V 0) (V 1)) (L (V 1) (V 0)))

  --  add = λ (x:nat) . λ (y:nat) . λ (a:*) . λ(s: a -> a) . λ (z : a) . (x a s (y a s z))
  let add = L nat (L nat (L S (L (L (V 0) (V 1)) (L (V 1) (A (A (A (V 4) (V 2)) (V 1)) (A (A (A (V 3) (V 2)) (V 1)) (V 0)))))))

  --  bool = ∀ (a:*) . a -> a -> a
  let bool = L S (L (V 0) (L (V 1) (V 2)))

  --  false = ∀ (a:*) . λ (x : a) . λ(y : a) . x
  let false = L S (L (V 0) (L (V 1) (V 0)))

  --  true = ∀ (a:*) . λ (x : a) . λ(y : a) . y
  let true = L S (L (V 0) (L (V 1) (V 1)))

  --  loop = ((λ (x:*) . (x x)) (λ (x:*) . (x x)))
  let loop = A (L S (A (V 0) (V 0))) (L S (A (V 0) (V 0)))

  --  natOrBoolId = λ (a:bool) . λ (t:(if a S then nat else bool)) . λ (x:t) . t
  let natOrBoolId = L bool (L (A (A (A (V 0) S) nat) bool) (V 0))

  -- nat
  let c0 = zero
  let c1 = A succ zero
  let c2 = A succ c1
  let c3 = A succ c2
  let c4 = A succ c3
  let c5 = A succ c4

  -- Tests
  let test name pass = putStrLn $ "- " ++ (if pass then "OK." else "ERR") ++ " " ++ name

  putStrLn "True and false are bools"
  test "typeof true  == bool " $ typeof true  == bool
  test "typeof false == bool " $ typeof false == bool

  putStrLn "Calling 'true nat' on two nats selects the first one"
  test "reduce (true nat c1 c2) == c1"  $ reduce (A (A (A true nat) c1) c2) == reduce c1
  test "typeof (true nat c1 c2) == nat" $ typeof (A (A (A true nat) c1) c2) == nat

  putStrLn "Calling 'true nat' on a bool is a type error"
  test "reduce (true nat true c2) == E" $ reduce (A (A (A true nat) true) c2) == E
  test "reduce (true nat c2 true) == E" $ reduce (A (A (A true nat) c2) true) == E

  putStrLn "More type errors"
  test "reduce (succ true) == E" $ reduce (A succ true) == E

  putStrLn "Addition works"
  test "reduce (add c2 c3) == c5"  $ reduce (A (A add c2) c3) == reduce c5
  test "typeof (add c2 c2) == nat" $ typeof (A (A add c2) c3) == nat

  putStrLn "Loop isn't typeable"
  test "typeof loop == E" $ typeof loop == E

  putStrLn "Function with type that depends on value"
  test "typeof (natOrBoolId true c2) == nat" $ typeof (A (A natOrBoolId true) c2) == nat
  test "typeof (natOrBoolId true true) == E" $ typeof (A (A natOrBoolId true) true) == E
  test "typeof (natOrBoolId false c2) == E" $ typeof (A (A natOrBoolId false) c2) == E
  test "typeof (natOrBoolId false true) == bool"  $ typeof (A (A natOrBoolId false) true) == bool
```

My question is, **what exactly makes a system consistent?** Specifically:

- What problems do I get from the things I did (removing Pi, merging infer/eval, etc.)? Can those be somehow "justified" (generating a different system but still "correct")?
- Basically: is it possible to fix this system (i.e., make it "suitable as the core of a dependently typed language just like CoC") while keeping it small?

[Runnable code.](http://lpaste.net/raw/284828)

Comment: Here's a little rule of thumb for consistency: are there any types which are not inhabited? If every type is inhabited, that's a pretty sure sign that it's inconsistent.

Comment: See [Simply Easy](http://strictlypositive.org/Easy.pdf) or [this series of lectures by Weirich](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AT4JJm_ujRg) (and [the code](https://github.com/sweirich/pi-forall)) for examples of small dependently-typed systems. I wouldn't say you've implemented a type checker, though (for example, I'd expect `typeof (VL x y)` to return a pi-type, not another lambda). I recommend [Types and Programming Languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) as an intro, I'm half way through it at the moment.

Comment: @DanielWagner how can I know if every type is inhabited? And if I know not every type is inhabited, then is it consistent?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson are you sure of that, and, if so, could you elaborate? Notice that on this system "VL" actually stands for both "λ" or "Pi" simultaneously (since they work the same way...). If it isn't a type checker, then why, for example, the type `nat` only checks for terms on the form `λ (n:*) . λ (s : n -> n) . λ n . s (s (s (s ... x)))`? If that isn't "type checking", then what exactly defines type checking? That is my confusion. (Note: I've read almost half of TAPL but I think it doesn't really cover those questions...)

Comment: @Viclib You can know every type is inhabited by giving a function which takes a type and produces a term of that type. Often this is quite easy; e.g. usually infinite loops can be given any type. I'm not sure if there is a consistent definition for consistent. Certainly I would squint a little if somebody did the following: 1. Start with Haskell's type system, which is easily shown inconsistent. 2. Adjoin a fresh type `UNINHABITED` and make it unreachable by any typing judgment. 3. Claim that this new system is consistent.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner, how would you make it unreachable? Since it's a type, it can be an argument to `(->)`, but then `boom :: Void -> UNINHABITED; boom = \case { }`. There is an isomorphism between `Void` and `forall a. a`, so if you can "inhabit" `Void`, you can "inhabit" anything.

Comment: "Notice that on this system "VL" actually stands for both "λ" or "Pi" simultaneously (since they work the same way...)" — Thorsten Altenkirch: "A function and its type are very different concepts even if they have some
superficial syntactic similarity. Especially for the newcomer this identification is very confusing and completely misleading. I do think that one should understand type theoretical concepts from what they mean and not how they look like".

Comment: And an immediate witness of Thorsten's words: you wrote `∀ (a:*) . (λ (x:a) . a)`, but `λ (x:a) . a` is not a type, so it can't be an argument to `∀`.

Comment: @user3237465 `UNINHABITED` could perfectly well be in a separate syntax class. I don't see any reason it must be allowed to be an argument to `(->)`. Remember: the goal of this system is not to be a good type system, but to be an explicit example of what not to do.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner, I'm not sure you can call it "type" then. Though, I'm not sure you can't.

Comment: @user3237465 I dare you to stop me. =)

Comment: @user3237465 I've read that thread where you took that quote from and also a paper about using just one constructor for both Pi/Lam, seems like that is actually the case on AutoMath and there is nothing fundamentally wrong with it! There is also an old question I asked with a lot of info on that regard. I'm still left wondering if my implementation here is a "good" system (whatever that means), which probably isn't the case since that paper seems to treat the constructor a little different than I do. This is all very confusing.

Comment: I was puzzled at first by `check VS b = True`, but then realized that since Pi=Lam in this system then _every_ term has type S (among others). I still wonder if that does not break something. It looks weird that when `typeof t == E` I can still have `typeof (A t' t) /= E` if `t' = \x:* -> ...`

Comment: `eval (L a b) typ ctx@(vs,ts,d) = VL a' b' where a' = eval a False ctx` Isn't `a` supposed to be a type there? Shouldn't the `Bool`ean flag be `True` instead of `False`?

Comment: @gallais [when **type checking** a Lam](http://lpaste.net/edit/284624), `a' = eval vs d a`, i.e., the nf value (not the type) of a'. [When evaluating a Lam or a Pi](http://lpaste.net/284627), the returned binder also has the nf value (not the type) of `a'`. So both cases need the nf (not type) of a', thus the flag is False. The only case left is when **type checking** Pi, which always returns **Star** (not a binder). This is the only asymmetry here, so this was one of the cases where I asked "OK what if I just forget the 'all types have type Star' rule, can the resulting system still be good'?

Comment: @chi I wonder that too. The fact every type has type S on the usual calculus doesn't break anything, though, so, should it? Also the fact you can have E inside a valid term is weird too, but E is quite a lazy hack here, it could be removed and just return `Either String Term` as usual, right.

Comment: If I understand the type system proposed on "Typed λ-calculi with one binder", they still have 2 different rules for Pi/λ, disambiguating by checking if the type of `a'` and `b'` are `Star`. So on that system you still have `typeof nat == Star`, which isn't the case on this one here. Do we **need** that `typeof nat == Star`? Can we make sense of not having all types have type `Star`?

Comment: Also note that the type of `loop` is `(S S)`, and I have no intuition about what this should mean. Also, the type of `(S S)` is... `(S S)` itself. Further, we have `typeof S = S` which might trigger Girard's paradox.

Comment: @chi what if we add box? (What **exactly** is the type of loop? I can't type it anymore with this update.)

Comment: I got `typeof loop = A S S` befure your update. I have no idea about what this type checker actually does, though.

Comment: @chi I added a case for non-function application so that is `typeof loop == E` now. Maybe I could rephrase the question as: whatever Morte does, doesn't that system do?

Comment: @Viclib Why do you talk about typechecking? Is `eval` not an evaluation function?

Comment: @gallais I mixed both since they're very similar, so `eval False` is evaluation, `eval True` is type-checking... maybe I should use a better name?

Comment: @Viclib You seem confused about the difference between pi-types and lambda-terms. They may look syntactically similar (they both bind variables) but they have totally different meanings. For example, a lambda-term can be applied to an argument but a pi-type can't. Likewise, type-checking (generating and comparing type information) and evaluation (reducing terms) are also very different operations: for example, type-checking can fail (`typeCheck :: Term -> Either TypeError Term`) whereas evaluation of a well-typed term can't (`eval :: Term -> Term`).

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I perfectly understand that they are different, but I'm not convinced the difference is natural or merely a fruit of human interpretation. The type checker presented here unifies both while apparently working identically to traditional λ-cube systems for type checking purposes; so, we have two options: either there is some flaw on my system (i.e., it doesn't make for a good type-checker) or the difference between Pi and Lam is not that relevant when writing an useful type-checker. That is exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: @Viclib I understand. But in such a system what's the meaning of a term like `(λ(x:A). x) y`? What's the thing on the left-hand side of the application: is it a lambda-term (which is fine) or a pi-type (which should be a type error)?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson but you're interpreting that system in terms of one which has Pi, which makes no sense, since there is no Pi. This is more or less how this situation feels: *"why do I need types?"* - *"to do X, Y and Z!"* - *"cool, how I implement them?"* - *"use Pi and Lam"* - *"ok, so I just implemented X, Y, Z without Pi... is it a valid type checker?"* - *"no"* - *"why?"* - *"because there is no Pi"* - *"but this system does X, Y, Z, which is what you told me types are for, so, why do I need Pi?"* - *"because without Pi, you wouldn't have Pi!"*

Comment: I think the reason I am confused by your system is that you haven't given a clear description of what each term in your syntax means. For example, I expect types (things that can appear on the right hand side of a type annotation) to be things of type `*`, whereas in your system you can write a lambda in a type annotation, and lambdas have a type of lambda. Perhaps I'd have an easier time understanding you if you tried formally writing down some typing rules?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I don't know well enough to write anything formally, I just know this system works similar to Morte. Notice on the tests I created types like Nat, Bool, functions on those types, etc. It all *works exactly like on Morte* (saying that as an engineer, not a scientist). So, *"if this system does the same as Morte, with one less constructor, then why do we need that extra constructor?"*... I'm expecting someone to explain that *"no, this system doesn't do all that Morte does because X"* (and then I learn something).

Comment: In order to make sure that simplified version of the type system behaves the same as the original one(by intuition that the original one behaves correctly) you may use Equational Reasoning as a tool to guarantee that the simplified one behaves the same as the original one. What is important is to have extensional equality that checks the result of the expressions in simplified and original versions of the type system.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *consistency* is a thing in mathematical logic, meaning that a logic doesn't contain a contradiction. I've seen people speaking about the "consistency" of type theories, but unfortunately it is not a well-defined term.

In the context of lambda calculus, many people use the term "consistency" to mean vastly different things. Some people say the untyped lambda-calculus is consistent, by which they mean that different derivations of a lambda-term lead to the same result (i.e. the Church-Rosser property). In that respect, most calculi are consistent.

However, *consistent* can also mean that the Curry-Howard isomorphic logic of the calculus is consistent. Simply-typed lambda-calculus corresponds to first-order intuitionistic logic (without equality), and when people say STLC is consistent they really mean that first-order intuitionistic logic is consistent. In this sense of consistency, consistency means that the bottom (void) type doesn't have an inhabitant (and, thus, a derivation). That is, every expression must produce a value with a valid type. Bottom corresponds to falsehood, so this means that falsehood can't be derived (because you can derive anything from falsehood).

Now, in this sense, to be consistent you can't have nontermination (`fix`), non-returning functions, or control operators (`call/cc` and friends). Haskell is not consistent in this sense, because you can write functions that produce arbitrary types (the function `f x = f x` has type `a -> b`; obviously, this isn't consistent). Similarly, you can return `undefined` from anything, making it producing something of the bottom type. So, to make sure that a type theory is consistent in this sense, you'd have to make sure that you *can't return the empty type from any expression*.

But then, in the first sense of "consistency", Haskell is consistent I believe (barring some wacky features). Equational equivalence should be good.